# how to update comboBox while using glazedList..evenlist

Tags: java, combobox, jcombobox, auto-update, glazedlists

alright.,ive already tried every trick off my sleeves..but couldnt figure out how to update the comboBox w/glazedList..if the input is coming from other class..ive tried passing the value to the methods,declaring it first to a string..and such..but none has work..tho it does work if the new item will just gonna come from same class..via click of a button..
     so far ive got this code..

```
 values = GlazedLists.eventListOf(auto);//auto is an array..
    AutoCompleteSupport.install(comboSearch,values);//comboSearch is the comboBox

//"x" is the value coming from another class.

public void updateCombo(String x){
        List<String> item = new ArrayList<>();
        item.add(x)
        value.addAll(item);
 }
```

i hope this codes are enough to interpret what im trying to ask..

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to see how you've created your combobox and your eventlist. Therefore I'll just create a simple example application from scratch that shows you the essentials.

Just in case you're not familiar the general concepts the main take home points are:

- Try and avoid using standard Java collections (eg ArrayList, Vector) and use the `EventList` class as soon as possible. All the goodness that comes with sorting/filtering/auto-complete relies on the EventList foundation so set one up asap and then simply manipulate (add/remove/etc) and then the GlazedLists plumbing will take care of the rest.
- Once you've got your collection of objects in an `EventList` and you want to leverage a swing component then look in the `ca.odell.glazedlists.swing` module which contains everything you need. In this instance you can use an `EventListComboBoxModel` - pass in your eventlist, and then set your JComboBox model to use the newly created `EventListComboBoxModel` and from that point GlazedLists will take care of ensuring your list data structure and combobox stay in sync.

So in my example I create an empty combobox and an button. Clicking the button will add an item per click into the combobox. The magic is simply the creation of the EventList and the use of `EventListComboBoxModel` to link the list to the combobox.

**Please note** that the code below was only tested against GlazedLists 1.8. But I'm pretty sure it'll work fine with 1.9 or 1.7 too.

```
public class UpdateComboBox {

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JComboBox cboItems;
    private EventList<String> itemsList = new BasicEventList<String>();

    public UpdateComboBox() {
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("GlazedLists Update Combobox Example");
        mainFrame.setSize(600, 400);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add Item");
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                itemsList.add("Item " + (itemsList.size()+1));
            }
        });

        // Use a GlazedLists EventComboBoxModel to connect the JComboBox with an EventList.
        EventComboBoxModel<String> model = new EventComboBoxModel<String>(itemsList);
        cboItems = new JComboBox(model);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(cboItems, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(addButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          new UpdateComboBox();
        }
    });
    }
}
```